# Issue with npx exp publish in Expo Go: 404 Error during Uploading Assets Phase

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, expo-go

I've created a brand new Expo Go app and signed up with an Expo Go account, logged in using exp login.

My App.json is below.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "SampleApp",
    "slug": "SampleApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "sdkVersion": "49.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "./assets/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.abywatson.SampleApp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I try to publish my app using following command.

```
npx exp publish
```

I get the following errors when I run 'npx exp publish'

```
We've built a brand new CLI for Expo!
Expo CLI is a drop in replacement for exp.
Install: npm install -g expo-cli
Use: expo --help
Read more: https://blog.expo.io/expo-cli-2-0-released-a7a9c250e99c
[11:09:14] Publishing to channel 'default'...
[11:09:15] Building iOS bundle
[11:09:15] Building Android bundle
[11:09:15] Analyzing assets
[11:09:18] Uploading assets
[11:09:18] Request failed with status code 404
[11:09:18] Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\aby\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\aby\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\aby\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:236:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Notes: I made sure all the assets are in the assets folder. Any help appreciated.